# Why does express-http-proxy seem to be ignoring the path?

Tags: express, express-http-proxy

I have the following...

```
const coreUrl = "myip:3000"
app.use('/login', proxy(coreUrl, options));
```

I would expect this to forward to `myip:3000/login` but it actually forwards to `myip:3000` I also tried using `coreUrl+"/login"` as well but that didn't seem to help.

How do I redirect with the correct path using this tool?

Answer (score 2):

I hit this today, and I found the "do things right" configuration. express-http-proxy strips the prefix that it matches from the path. There is a way to put it back on, with the `proxyReqPathResolver` option. Here is what worked:

```
import express from "express";
import proxy from "express-http-proxy";

const app = express();

app.use(
  "/login",
  proxy("http://localhost:4318", {
    proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
      return "/login" + req.url;
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy#host), the first argument to `express-http-proxy` is the host without a path. [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) seems to offer more options.